# JSON data undefined while using in HTML

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular, typescript, angular-fullstack

I am new to Angular and Node and have been working on a full stack development. I am reading the data on Angular from Node which I have connected to MySQL. I am somehow stuck at outputting my data on an HTML page. I am getting the error of undefined when I try to access my data in my HTML.

[This is the JSON data that I have read on my console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S10su.png)

This is my typescript code that converts JSON object to string:

```
private onFetchPosts()
{
  this.http
  .get<{[key: string]: DataBase}>('http://localhost:3000/show')      //Here, DataBase is an interface
  .pipe(map(responseData => {
    const postsArray: DataBase[] = [];
    for (const key in responseData){
      if(responseData.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        postsArray.push({...responseData[key], idoffice: key});
      }
    }
    return postsArray;
  }))
  .subscribe(posts => {

    this.dbData = posts;                                           
    console.log(this.dbData);
  });
}
```

When I try to access this data in my HTML code:

```
<h3>test print</h3>
<li class="list-group-item" *ngFor = "let db of dbData"></li>
<p>{{ db.ActivityType }}</p>
```

Then, I get this error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'ActivityType' of undefined
```

Can you please help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `db.ActivityType` inside `li` .

```
<li class="list-group-item" *ngFor = "let db of dbData">
    <p>{{ db.ActivityType }}</p>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I can't believe this error was due to this. :)

Comment: glad you found an answer i thought it was trying to compile the template prior to the call being made and dbData is set, but this is a good catch

Answer (score 0):

```
<h3>test print</h3>
<li class="list-group-item" *ngFor = "let db of dbData">
<p>{{ db.ActivityType }}</p>
</li>
```

**li tag closed wrongly.**